# C++: Matching regex, what is in smatch?

Tags: c++, regex

I'm using a modified regex example from Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed. Page 127 & 128.  I'm trying to understand what is in the vector `smatch matches`.

```
$ ./a.out
AB00000-0000
AB00000-0000.-0000.

$ ./a.out
AB00000
AB00000..
```

It seems like the matches in parenthesis `()` appear in `match[1], match[2], ...` which the total match appears in `match[0]`.

Appreciate any insight into this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ZIP code pattern: XXddddd-dddd and variants
    regex pat (R"(\w{2}\s*\d{5}(-\d{4})?)");

    for (string line; getline(cin,line);) {
        smatch matches; // matched strings go here
        if (regex_search(line, matches, pat)) { // search for pat in line
            for (auto p : matches) {
                cout << p << ".";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `matches` is a [`std::match_results`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results), not a `vector`, but it does have an `operator[]`.

From the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/operator_at):

> If n == 0, returns a reference to the std::sub_match representing the part of the target sequence matched by the entire matched regular expression.
>
> If n > 0 and n < size(), returns a reference to the std::sub_match representing the part of the target sequence that was matched by the nth captured marked subexpression).

where `n` is the argument to `operator[]`. So `matches[0]` contains the entire matched expression, and `matches[1]`, `matches[2]`, ... contain consecutive capture group expressions.